# ValueError: [E088] Text of length 1027203 exceeds maximum of 1000000. spacy

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

Пытаюсь составить корпус слов по тексту. Проблема в том , что текст очень большой и я получаю исключение:

```
ValueError: [E088] Text of length 1027203 exceeds maximum of 1000000. The v2.x parser and NER models require roughly 1GB of temporary memory per 100,000 characters in the input. This means long texts may cause memory allocation errors. If you're not using the parser or NER, it's probably safe to increase the `nlp.max_length` limit. The limit is in number of characters, so you can check whether your inputs are too long by checking `len(text)`.
```

Безопасно ли повысить `nlp.max_length`?
Вот код:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('fr_core_news_md')
f = open("text.txt")
doc = nlp(''.join(ch for ch in f.read() if ch.isalnum() or ch == " "))
f.close()
del f
words = []
for token in doc:
    if token.lemma_ not in words:
        words.append(token.lemma_)

f = open("corpus.txt", 'w')
f.write("Number of words:" + str(len(words)) + "\n" + ''.join([i + "\n" for i in sorted(words)]))
f.close()
```

#### Update

При попытке сделать так все равно получаю ту же ошибку:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('fr_core_news_md')
nlp.max_length = 1027203
f = open("text.txt")
doc = nlp(''.join(ch for ch in f.read() if ch.isalnum() or ch == " "))
f.close()
del f
words = []
for token in doc:
    if token.lemma_ not in words:
        words.append(token.lemma_)

f = open("corpus.txt", 'w')
f.write("Number of words:" + str(len(words)) + "\n" + ''.join([i + "\n" for i in sorted(words)]))
f.close()
```

Comment: Попробуйте вызвать nlp с параметром disable = ['ner', 'parser'], как в данном примере: doc = nlp("The sentences we'd like doing lemmatization on", disable = ['ner', 'parser'])

Comment: @CrazyElf Не сработало:   ```ValueError: [E088] Text of length 1027203 exceeds maximum of 1000000. The v2.x parser and NER models require roughly 1GB of temporary memory per 100,000 characters in the input. This means long texts may cause memory allocation errors. If you're not using the parser or NER, it's probably safe to increase the `nlp.max_length` limit. The limit is in number of characters, so you can check whether your inputs are too long by checking `len(text)`.```

Comment: Ну, я читал, что это возможно баг в свежей версии Spacy, тогда с этим ничего пока нельзя сделать. Но эти параметры запомните - они попогут сэкономить память.

Comment: @CrazyElf  В какую версию поставить, чтобы работала стабильно(python 3.7) ?

Comment: Я не могу сейчас найти, гуглил по ключевым словам, вылезал тред с issue на гитхабе, где обсуждали эту проблему. С какой-то более старой версией вроде не ругалось, но с какой - не помню.

Comment: @CrazyElf [?](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102610/discussion-between-victor-says-reinstate-monica-and-crazyelf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57231616/valueerror-e088-text-of-length-1027203-exceeds-maximum-of-1000000-spacy)

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('fr_core_news_md')
nlp.max_length = 1030000 # or higher
f = open("text.txt")
doc = nlp(''.join(ch for ch in f.read() if ch.isalnum() or ch == " "))
f.close()
del f
words = []
for token in doc:
    if token.lemma_ not in words:
        words.append(token.lemma_)

f = open("corpus.txt", 'w')
f.write("Number of words:" + str(len(words)) + "\n" + ''.join([i + "\n" for i in sorted(words)]))
f.close()
```